# Cannot access installed packages from another assembly

Tags: visual-studio, mvvm-light, .net-assembly, class-library

I have a UWP application that should be written in WPF. I am using MVVM approach and in my project I have a WPF project and 2 class libraries. One is for Model the other one is for ViewModel. I have installed MVVM Light framework in my ViewModel and added a reference from my View to my ViewModel. I am currently trying to make a navigation from one page to another but it seems that I dont have access to MVVM Light libraries from my View project. In UWP I don't have any issues with that. Can anyone explain to me what am I doing wrong? I just want to have access to libraries which are installed in class library which I have a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly call a library referenced indirectly by another library from your application; you will need to add a reference to the "grandchild" library directly to the application.

Currently you have this:

> Application -> LibraryA -> LibraryB

You will need to add another reference, like this:

> Application -> LibraryA -> LibraryB
>
> Application -> LibraryB

Comment: How can I do that and for the first time I hear about grandchild library?

Comment: "grandchild library" was just the best description for an indirect reference I could come up with.  It isn't a real term.

Comment: So you mean that I should ALSO install MVVM Light library to my application project?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  This dependency chain is partially why `nuget` is so popular. `nuget packages` can specify dependencies that automatically get installed.  If you library was deployed as a nuget package and specified mvvm light as a dependency, anyone installing your library via nuget would also automatically get a reference to mvvm light.  If your library is for internal use only, it is probably easier to just remember the dependencies and add them automatically.

Comment: It is kind of weird since I have no problems with it in my UWP application where I can access these libraries. I guess I will go installing them here there too. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible for your UWP application to do that; .NET just doesn't work that way.  I'd double check the references to make sure that one didn't get added at some point.